# Cocoapods error while installing Swift library in Objective-C project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I am working with objective-C, i wanted to implement a Charts in it which is in Swift. While installing pod i got this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wO07Z.png):
"Pods written in Swift can only be integrated as frameworks; add `use_frameworks!` to your Podfile or target to opt into using it. The Swift Pod being used is: Charts"
How can i use this Library in my project ?

Comment: please show your podfile!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Swift pods directly in the project using pods written in Swift and Objective-C. Swift pods can only be created as frameworks. Objective-C pods can be created as frameworks and with source code files directly as well. There is a catch when you include use_frameworks!, all the pods have to be frameworks. So you need to check if the Objective-C pods that you have included have framework pods.